# JSON object calling issue

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object

I have issue with JSON formatting, my code is as below,

```
const res =  JSON.stringify(results[1]);
```

my result is,

```
result {
     "0": {
         "name":"elezabeth",
          "job":"accountant"
       },
    "1": {
         "name":"anna",
         "job":"lawyer"
       }
}
```

I need to assign result as

```
details {
    {
    "name": "Elizabeth",
    "job": "accountant"
    },
    {
    "name": "anna",
    "job": "lawyer"
    }
}
```

can anybody give idea on that ?

Comment: Is result an object or an array? And is result = results[1]? Also are "details" and "result" keys in a object or variable names?

Comment: Your desired result is not a valid JavaScript data structure. Is `details` meant to be an array instead of an object? If so, perhaps you want `const res = JSON.stringify(Object.values(results[1]))`. See [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: @Phil - thanks for your answer, it really worked

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as an array like this:

```
const res =  JSON.stringify(Object.values(results[1]));


[
  { name: 'elezabeth', job: 'accountant' },
  { name: 'anna', job: 'lawyer' }
]
```

You can not get it as an object without keys. (I mean "0" and "1" in your object.)